# Faraday::ConnectionFailed, Connection refused - connect(2) for “localhost” port 9200 Error Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch

I am trying to add Searchkick gem in my app with Ruby on Rails but when i type a word in my search box i get this error in my app. I have installed elasticsearch and the latest version of java as required but still the error is the same. This is the error i am getting :

> Faraday::ConnectionFailed in PostsController#search
>
> Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9200

Here's my code:

The Terminal shows that elastic search is installed:

**Terminal**

```
Warning: elasticsearch-1.7.3 already installed
```

**posts_controller.rb**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


def search
  if params[:search].present?
    @posts = Post.search(params[:search])
  else
    @posts = Post.all
  end
end
  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /posts/new
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update(post_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url, notice: 'Post was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:name)
    end
end
```

**model/post.rb**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchkick
end
```

**views/post/index.html.erb**

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<%= form_tag search_posts_path, method: :get, class: "navbar-form navbar-right", role: "search" do %>
        <p>
          <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], class: "form-control" %>
          <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil, class: "btn btn-default" %>
        </p>
      <% end %>

<h1>Listing Posts</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @posts.each do |post| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= post.name %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', post %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Post', new_post_path %>
```

**views/search.html.erb**

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Search Result</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @posts.each do |post| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= post.name %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', post %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**config/routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts do
  collection do
    get 'search'
  end
end
end
```

This is the screen i am getting with the error shown :

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9200
```

Looks like your elastic search service is not running. You have to make sure it's running.

To see if your elastic search service is running, run:

```
curl localhost:9200
```

If it's running, then it should return a hash like this:

```
{
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "Buzz",
  "cluster_name" : "your_cluster_name",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "1.4.5",
    "build_hash" : "...",
    "build_timestamp" : "2015-04-27T08:06:06Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.10.4"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

If elastic search is not running which is most likely the case for you, start it using this command:

```
sudo service elasticsearch start
```

That should fix your problem.

Comment: `sudo service elasticsearch start` give me the message "sudo: service: command not found"

Comment: @Dan if you're using Mac  then you should try using `brew services start elasticsearch`