# Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:9200 (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9200) (Faraday::ConnectionFailed)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tcp, ubuntu-14.04

I am getting the error: Puma caught this error: Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:9200 (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9200) (Faraday::ConnectionFailed) in my rails application in ubuntu 14.04.

below is the output of my elastic search in terminal:

```
prashanth@prashanth-OptiPlex-390:~$ sudo service elasticsearch restart
 * Starting Elasticsearch Server                                                                                                               prashanth@prashanth-OptiPlex-390:~$ sudo service elasticsearch start
 * Starting Elasticsearch Server                                                                                                                * Already running.                                                                                                                     [ OK ] 
prashanth@prashanth-OptiPlex-390:~$ curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200'
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused
prashanth@prashanth-OptiPlex-390:~$
```

here are the my elastic search settings in `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml` file

```
network.host: 127.0.0.1
transport.tcp.port: 9200
http.port: 9200
```

error description:

```
Puma caught this error: Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:9200 (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9200) (Faraday::ConnectionFailed)
/home/prashanth/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:882:in `rescue in block in connect'
/home/prashanth/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:879:in `block in connect'
/home/prashanth/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/timeout.rb:91:in `block in timeout'
/home/prashanth/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/timeout.rb:101:in `timeout'
/home/prashanth/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:878:in `connect'
/home/prashanth/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
/home/prashanth/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
/home/prashanth/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:1398:in `request'
/home/prashanth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/faraday-0.10.1/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:83:in `perform_request'
/home/prashanth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/faraday-0.10.1/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:41:in `block in call'
/home/prashanth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/faraday-0.10.1/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:88:in `with_net_http_connection'
/home/prashanth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/faraday-0.10.1/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:33:in `call'
/home/prashanth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/faraday-0.10.1/lib/faraday/rack_builder.rb:139:in `build_response'
/home/prashanth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/faraday-0.10.1/lib/faraday/connection.rb:377:in `run_request'
/home/prashanth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/elasticsearch-transport-5.0.0/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/http/faraday.rb:23:in `block in perform_request'
/home/prashanth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/elasticsearch-transport-5.0.0/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:257:in `perform_request'
/home/prashanth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/elasticsearch-transport-5.0.0/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/http/faraday.rb:20:in `perform_request'
/home/prashanth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/elasticsearch-transport-5.0.0/lib/elasticsearch/transport/client.rb:128:in `perform_request'
```

Comment: if you just run 'elasticsearch' in terminal, will it start?

Comment: had the same, tried many solutions but re-installing using `deb` package fixed mine
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-elasticsearch-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 6):

In the settings you posted, your HTTP and TCP ports have the same port number assigned

```
network.host: 127.0.0.1
transport.tcp.port: 9200
http.port: 9200
```

I would suggest changing the `transport.tcp.port` and trying again.

Try using the defaults unless you already have port 9300 in use:

```
network.host: 127.0.0.1
transport.tcp.port: 9300
http.port: 9200
```

If you are still facing issues, you may need to open up the ports on your firewall program. On Ubuntu, this is likely UFW.

If your service script has a status function, this may tell you if your Elasticsearch instance has started up properly or not. Failing this, you can use `ps aux` to determine if it is running.

```
$ sudo service elasticsearch status
```

Or

```
$ ps aux | grep elasticsearch
```

As pointed out in similar questions, cURL can give a refused connection error when Elasticsearch isn't running (source: [Faraday::ConnectionFailed, Connection refused - connect(2) for “localhost” port 9200 Error Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33375382/faradayconnectionfailed-connection-refused-connect2-for-localhost-port?rq=1)).

Comment: uninstalling and reinstalling the elastic search, solved my problem.

Comment: Good to hear. That means it was most likely a configuration issue then. I'd say the port numbers as mentioned in the first part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Docker? The only solution for me was unninstall Docker completely.
Otherwhise, i think the problem is something about the port that docker use.

If you don't use alot like me, just remove it and you're good to go.