# 500 error message rails heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I get an error when saving records or having a POST or DELETE request to my db on Heroku. This is my first time deploying a rails app on heroku and I don't know what can be causing the issue. I have also searched online and read the logs but still no sign of cause. The strange thing is the record gets saved but it shows me a 500 message.

Delete method:

`def destroy
    if @contact.destroy
      flash[:success] = "Successfully deleted contact"
      redirect_to root_path
    else 
      flash[:warning] = "Problem encountered while deleting the current contact."
    end
  end`

Log:

> 2017-08-02T12:29:20.368457+00:00 app[web.1]: D,
>   [2017-08-02T12:29:20.368375 #4] DEBUG -- :
>   [486f4051-00b0-4d23-8d56-6de722606384] (1.5ms) BEGIN
>   2017-08-02T12:29:20.371200+00:00 app[web.1]: D,
>   [2017-08-02T12:29:20.371130 #4] DEBUG -- :
>   [486f4051-00b0-4d23-8d56-6de722606384] SQL (1.9ms) DELETE FROM
>   "contacts" WHERE "contacts"."id" = $1 [["id", 2]]
>   2017-08-02T12:29:20.374283+00:00 app[web.1]: D,
>   [2017-08-02T12:29:20.374212 #4] DEBUG -- :
>   [486f4051-00b0-4d23-8d56-6de722606384] (2.8ms) COMMIT
>   2017-08-02T12:29:20.376028+00:00 app[web.1]: D,
>   [2017-08-02T12:29:20.375962 #4] DEBUG -- :
>   [486f4051-00b0-4d23-8d56-6de722606384] Contact Remove (1.4ms)
>   {"id":2,"exception":["Faraday::ConnectionFailed","Failed to open TCP
>   connection to localhost:9200 (Connection refused - connect(2) for
>   \"localhost\" port 9200)"],"exception_object":"Failed to open TCP
>   connection to localhost:9200 (Connection refused - connect(2) for
>   \"localhost\" port 9200)"} 2017-08-02T12:29:20.376531+00:00
>   app[web.1]: I, [2017-08-02T12:29:20.376443 #4] INFO -- :
>   [486f4051-00b0-4d23-8d56-6de722606384] Completed 500 Internal Server
>   Error in 20ms (Searchkick: 1.4ms | ActiveRecord: 10.5ms)
>   2017-08-02T12:29:20.377484+00:00 app[web.1]: F,
>   [2017-08-02T12:29:20.377420 #4] FATAL -- :
>   [486f4051-00b0-4d23-8d56-6de722606384]
>   2017-08-02T12:29:20.377573+00:00 app[web.1]: F,
>   [2017-08-02T12:29:20.377489 #4] FATAL -- :
>   [486f4051-00b0-4d23-8d56-6de722606384] Faraday::ConnectionFailed
>   (Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:9200 (Connection refused -
>   connect(2) for "localhost" port 9200)):
>   2017-08-02T12:29:20.377644+00:00 app[web.1]: F,
>   [2017-08-02T12:29:20.377572 #4] FATAL -- :
>   [486f4051-00b0-4d23-8d56-6de722606384]
>   2017-08-02T12:29:20.377714+00:00 app[web.1]: F,
>   [2017-08-02T12:29:10.377644 #4] FATAL -- :
>   [486f4051-00b0-4d23-8d56-6de7226w06384]
>   app/controllers/user/contacts_controller.rb:27:in  ``destroy'
>   2017-08-02T12:29:29.530605+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET
>   path="/user/contacts" host=hhjjh.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=62545ba4-c37b-4167-bcf8-24a403638sd0 fwd="194.201.21.36"
>   dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=17ms status=200 bytes=7664
>   protocol=https

Comment: Seems elastic search server not started.

Comment: Are you sure that your connection is being handled correctly?

" Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:9200 (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9200)) "

You are deploying to heroku and it is trying to connect with localhost?

Comment: Also are you sure that you databse.yml is correct? You must have something like this:

production:
  <<: *default
  database: xxxxx
  username: xxxxx
  password: <%= ENV['xxxxx_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>

Comment: @gabriel  The records gets saved but doesn't do the proper redirect. If that is missing will it still save ?

Comment: FYI you can do a simple `Record.find(id).destroy` and then `raise "Stop"`, running this code will still destroy the record (unless in a DB transaction with the `raise`) but will fail on the `raise` line. Your problem is not related to the destroy call (because it is successful), it is elsewhere.

Comment: @d_invisible100 if the record is being saved I guess your database is correct. When you do a post request, you receive params, do something and then redirects like this for example: redirect_to "http://www.rubyonrails.org". How are you redirecting, could you post your code please.

Comment: @GabrielMesquita I just updated the question

Comment: Also, it works perfectly in development env

Comment: Since it works in dev env, i assume your root_path is correct. But it is really weird that the record is being saved. If you go to heroku console and type rails c, you can assert that the record is there?

Comment: Yes its there... I tried saving a new one through the heroku console and I got an error after it saved.. `{"id":6,"exception":["Faraday::ConnectionFailed","Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:9200 (Connection refused - connect(2) for \"localhost\" port 9200)"],"exception_object":"Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:9200 (Connection refused - connect(2) for \"localhost\" port 9200)"}
Faraday::ConnectionFailed: Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:9200 (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9200)`

Comment: @d_invisible100 are you using elastic search or Searchkick gem?

Comment: @d_invisible100 take a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33375382/faradayconnectionfailed-connection-refused-connect2-for-localhost-port?rq=1 I think that you have some service that it is not started on heroku. Look at your gemfile and see if you have the correct gems at you production env.

Comment: @Gabriel I am using Searchkick gem

Comment: I think that is the problem. You have to start the service at heroku so the gem will work.

Comment: @GabrielMesquita It works now. I added the elastic search addon and migrated. Thanks for your efforts :)

Comment: Great ! If the comments helped give an upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add the elasticsearch addon provided by heroku and re-migrated the database. Thanks everyone :)