# Elasticsearch can't be found when trying to migrate database using searchkick

Tags: macos, elasticsearch, installation, homebrew

Following this guide from [searchkick](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#getting-started), I installed elasticsearch from brew by running

```
$ brew install elasticsearch
```

And then I started it using the command

```
$ brew services start elasticsearch
==> Successfully started `elasticsearch` (label: homebrew.mxcl.elasticsearch)
```

However I'm getting the error

```
Faraday::ConnectionFailed: Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9200
```

Whenever I try to run a rake db:migrate or seed. Additionally if I run curl `localhost:9200` as [recommended here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33375382/faradayconnectionfailed-connection-refused-connect2-for-localhost-port?rq=1) it returns

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused
```

I've tried restarting elasticsearch (`brew services restart elasticsearch`), reinstall, and even restarting my machine, but nothing seems to work. If I had to guess, it seems as though it's running on the wrong port, but I'm not sure how to change this.

I'd really appreciate any pointers or suggestions, thanks.

Edit: if I go into `/usr/local/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml` and add two commands, `network.host: localhost` and `http.port: 9200`, I'll be able to go into the console and add things using the Group.create(...) function. It will return the faraday error, but it will still add it to the db, which I can view in a webpage. rake db:seed still does not work and returns the faraday error. I'm starting to think it may be a permissions error

Comment: did you check if your elasticsearch process if running or not? by checking it in process list, like `ps aux | grep elastic `

Comment: @es-enthu If I run that command I get `MY-USER           64916 133.7 11.7  6792188 984956   ??  R     7:47PM   0:04.56 /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 - ...  .6/libexec -Des.path.conf=/usr/local/etc/elasticsearch -Des.distribution.flavor=oss -Des.distribution.type=tar -cp /usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch/6.8.6/libexec/lib/* org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch`

Comment: So it look like it's running, although I had to cut out a lot of it to fit it in the comment. I can add the rest to the original post in an edit if that'd be better

Comment: yeah by looking at your output, sure its running :-)